# Convergence of a non-iid series

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, random-variables

Let $\mathbf y \in \mathbb C^N$ be a gaussian random vector with covariance matrix $C_{\mathbf y}$, then $\mathbf x = C_{\mathbf y} ^\frac{-1}{2} \mathbf y$ will be an i.i.d random vector. For a given (deterministic) matrix $\mathbf A \in \mathbb C^{N \times N}$ we have (based on random matrix theorem)

$$\frac{1}{N} \mathbf x ^ {H} \mathbf A \ \mathbf x \rightarrow \frac{1}{N} \operatorname{tr}(\mathbf A)$$

almost surely when $N \rightarrow \infty$.

I wanted to know whether there is any convergence for the following case. Imagine random vector $\mathbf r = \operatorname{sign}(\mathbf y)$, and $\mathbf u =  C_{\mathbf r} ^\frac{-1}{2} \mathbf r$, now

$$\frac{1}{N} \mathbf u ^ {H} \mathbf A \ \mathbf u \rightarrow {?}$$

I think $\mathbf u$ is not i.i.d, but at least we can say it's uncorrelated and identically distributed.